# Django optimize recursive query

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, optimization

I have this Django model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='subordinates', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    is_admin_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ****
```

Also, I have this recursive function, that calls on every instance of an employee in DRF serializer:

```
    def _get_admin_manager(self, obj):
    if not obj:
        return None
    if obj.is_admin_manager:
        return obj
    return self._get_admin_manager(obj.manager)
```

The problem is, the more complex vertical hierarchy, the more requests to DB will be created.
Is there is a way to optimize this?

Comment: you can pull related data using left join, it will reduce no of queries to the database.

Comment: Found one possible way to do this by, PostgreSQL recursive queries.

Comment: did anyone found a better solution to this issue ? I'm facing almost the same problem. after searching for days I found the best solution is to combine using `select_related()` or `prefetch_related()` with recursion. but how to implement that concept still blur!